# toggle button coded with javascript in blade file cannot save status in database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

in my blade file (written in PHP with a javascript section) I am trying to update an SQLite database field depending on the status of like, unlike button.

I tried to use some code I found on the pusher website (realtime-likes-laravel), but the snip that is supposed to update the DB is not working, the button changes status but it does not keep the status (when I refresh it the status is back to like and it does not keep unlike active). 
I believe that the issue is the lack of connection with the DB, unfortunately, I am not a Java dev, so I am not sure how to do it properly.

This is my button in the Blade file
                                        id }}">Like

This is my js section where I toggle

```
<script>

    var toggleButtonText = {
        Like: function(button) {
            button.textContent = "Unlike";
        },

        Unlike: function(button) {
            button.textContent = "Like";
        }
    };

    var actOnPushB = function (event) {
        var action = event.target.textContent;
        toggleButtonText[action](event.target);
    };

</script>
```

the page shows the button and the button toggles without any issue, but when I refresh the button is back to like status, also the DB is not updated.
I need the field likes_count in my database table answer to increment from 0 to 1 when liked and from 1 to 0 when unliked.

Comment: There seem to be two separate problems, one being that the status is not saved to the database and the other that the status is not show on the page. Can you please show us the code that shows the button, and the code that should save the status to the database?

Comment: Can you post the code of the button please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I worked with a friend who is a JS dev and he helped me to understand how to do the like / unlike buttons.

```
@section('js')
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
/* selector is like CSS selectors, it recalls the class automatically when it finds it in the code */
/*
* <div id="content"></div> --> $('#content')
* <input data-id="4" /> --> $('input[data-id="4"]')
*
* */
            $('.like-button').click(function () {
                var button = $(this);
                var status = parseInt(button.attr('data-status'));
                if(status==0) {
                    button.html('Unlike');
                    status = 1;
                }
                else{
                    button.html('Like');
                    status = 0;
                }
                $.ajax({
                   type: 'post',
                   url: 'toggleLike',
                   data: {answer_id:button.attr('data-id'), status:status},
                   success: function(data){
                       button.attr('data-status', status);
                   }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

in the PHP part, I added this to reference the page that will be used for the toggle

```
  </a>
                                        <button class="like-button" data-status="{{$answer->likes_count}}" data-id="{{ $answer->id }}">@if($answer->likes_count>0){{'Unlike'}}@else{{'Like'}}@endif</button>
                                </div>
```

then in the controller I added the function to handle the button toggling.

```
 public function like(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $action = $request->get('action');
        switch ($action) {
            case 'Like':
                Answer::where('id', $id)->increment('likes_count');
                break;
            case 'Unlike':
                Answer::where('id', $id)->decrement('likes_count');
                break;
        }
        return '';
    }
```

the last part was to add to the web routes the following line :

```
Route::post('/question/toggleLike', 'AnswerController@toggleLike')->name('answers.toggleLike');
```

and that was it.

Do not judge if this code is useful or not, it was for homework so only the logged-in user can answer the questions, create the questions and like the answers he gave to his own question.